# Python find all sub arrays of an array, that have length greater than 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a python array `b`

`>>> print b`

`[array([0]), array([47, 48, 49, 50]), array([97, 98, 99])]`

I want to find the first element of all sub-arrays whose lenth is greater than 1

i.e. I want `47 and 97`

How do I achieve this result using `numpy.where` or otherwise?

I tried `numpy.where( numpy.array(b).shape > 1 )` but it gives wrong result.

Comment: Numpy is misused here... `[x[0] for x in b if len(x) > 1]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thx. pls add that as answer.

Comment: It's actually somewhat of a duplicate, I'll sign it for you. Happy to help though.